# How to change doctrine entity auto_mapping namespace?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

In Symfony3 the `auto_mapping` option (*under the "doctrine" configuration section*) is looking for namespace "Entity" by default and I would appreciate rather "Entities".

Is there any way to change this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see in the [DoctrineBundle Configuration ("doctrine") Reference](http://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine.html), there are many ways to change where to put your entities/model as described in:

- [Custom Mapping Entities in a Bundle](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/doctrine.html#custom-mapping-entities-in-a-bundle)
- [Mapping Entities Outside of a Bundle](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/doctrine.html#mapping-entities-outside-of-a-bundle)

If you only want to change from `Entity` (default mapping) to `Entities` (your custom one) you need to change the configuration in `config.yml`.

**Using Annotations**:

```
auto_mapping: false
mappings:
    HelloBundle
        type: annotation
        prefix: Acme\HelloBundle\Entities
```

Then you can put all entities for `HelloBundle` in the relative `Entities` folder.